# Joining the tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there anyway in sql that can do something like,

```
Select table1.id, table2.admit, table2.value 
  from table2 join table1 
    on IDs
```

If the `id` in `table1` does not have value in `admit` column, make it `null` (*`admit` has either `1` or `0` only in `table2`*).

Which means i get all the ids in table1.

Here is the table output I need:

```
id      admit   value
1256    0       Ad
1254    1       Na
1255    0       Bk
1252    null    null

table1
id
1256
1254
1255
1252

table2
id      admit   value
1256    0   Ad
1254    1   Na
1255    0   Bk
1257    1   Ww
```

Help appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and a desired result? I'm fairly sure it's doable, I just don't understand the "rules" you're giving.

Comment: edited the question. Hope it is clear

Answer (score 3):

This will yield the results you are asking for:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ADMIT, T2.VALUE
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Here is a [good article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) on a few of the different SQL joins.

Based on @Nate's comment, here is what he's indicating:

```
SELECT T1.ID, ISNULL(T2.ADMIT,0), ISNULL(T2.VALUE,'-NO ENTRY-')
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: "If the id in table1 does not have value in 'admit' make it null" - where are you checking the value  in `admit in the above query..?

Comment: Nulls can be a little dangerous depending on use-case... If this might be true for your code, it would be prudent to turn nulls into some sentinel value. Changing T2.ADMIT to ISNULL(T2.ADMIT, [insert sentinel value here]) would do the trick.

Comment: "('admit' has either 1 or 0 only in table2)" -- assuming I don't need to... I'm assuming he wants all from Table1, but when nothing in Table2 show null -- left join handles that.  If I'm wrong, I told him to add example data.

Comment: @if that's not what he wants then why should he mention it in question..? -_-

Comment: Perhaps it's a language issue... that's how I perceived it.  And based on his latest update showing Table1/Table2 -- I was right.

Comment: yes it was (according to edit)... but you're answer wasn't right prior edit. you can't provide a *correct* answer until the requirement is clear.

Comment: I get it, you don't want garbage answers on here.  I'd have gladly deleted my answer if I was mistaken.

Comment: forgot to mention, in table2 both admit and value are 'not null', so there is no null value in table2. but I want null in my output, if id does not have admit or value

Comment: My answer still applies.  It's not based on the "value" of `admin`/`value`, it works based on the existence of the `ID` in `Table2`.

Comment: @jiggsJedi, table2 has '0' and '1' for admit, and I don't want to replace '0'. How would I pass isnull function?

Comment: Use the top query then... not the one with `isnull` in it.